# mysql table join with max()

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, max, min

I have problem with query using JOIN and MAX/MIN. For Example:

```
SELECT Min(a.date), Max(a.date) 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON b.ID = a.ID AND b.cID = 5
```

Its possible to add index or change this query result was better? 
Below the result of explain

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+-----+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys   | key | key_len | ref       | rows   | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+-----+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b        | ref  | PRIMARY,cID     | cID | 5       | const     | 680648 | Using index           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a        | ref  | ID              | ID  | 5       | base.b.ID |      1 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+-----+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+
```

Sorry, but I would not put here the whole table, and could make a lot of confusion.

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
) 

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `bID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID` int(11)  NOT NULL,
  `cID` int(11) DEFAULT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bID`),
  KEY `cID` (`cID`),
)
```

Comment: Please, try to explain `result was better`. Do you mean to obtain more fields, faster, ...?

Comment: Provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well

Comment: Yes, I mean the execution time query. I know how to use the index to speed up results MAX and MIN in a single query, but I am looking for a solution for the version with JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

```
b:  INDEX(cID, ID)
```

will make that a "covering" index, so it will probably get through the 680648 rows faster.  It should *replace* the current `KEY(cID)`.

Key_len for `b` is 5.  That disagrees with the table definition; something got simplified too much.

Comment: `^1` Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932151/how-to-get-ids-of-4-distinct-values-combination-of-2-keys

Comment: It does not help because need get 680648 rows to look for max and min. Normally if add INDEX(cID, date) to table a know max and min, work vary fast but its now work with JOIN.

Comment: @SilverRAT - `cID` and `date` seem to be in different tables, so the index can't work?

Comment: Also I think so, but I wanted to make sure, and to hear it from someone with more experience. Thank you for your help @Rick James